# React native absolute being hidden by parent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

When I have an absolute scrollview inside of a view, where the view is position relative and the scrollview is absolute, the contents of the absolute scrollview are hidden outside of the view, this occurs even if I have the parent view set as `oveflow: "hidden"`

I am trying it create a auto suggest drop down for a text input.

I have seen that this is an issue on android, but I am testing this on IOS and I am having the same issues.

From what I understood what I am doing should work as shown in this JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/qax6dvrc/14/)

But it looks like this:
[image]

**Styling**

```
const styles = {
    destinationInputContainer: {
        width: '90%',
        height: 50,
        
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
    
        marginBottom: '2.5%',
        marginHorizontal: '5%',

        // IOS
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 4},
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 1,
        elevation: 3,
        position: "relative",
        flexDirection: "row",
      },
      destinationInput: {
          paddingLeft: 10,
          paddingTop: 0,
          flex: 1,
      },
      searchResults: {
          position: "absolute",
          top: 50,
          zIndex: 1,
          elevation: 5,
      },
      topContainer: {
          position: "relative",
          overflow: "visible"
      }
}
```

Component Structure ( I have tried to remove all irrelevant code)

```
const DestinationInput = ({ _currentTextValue, _latLong, dragCallback, id, updateCallback}: destinationInputProps) => {

    const updateValue = (newValue: string) => {
        setCurrentText(newValue);  // update the value stored in the state
        updateCallback(inputId, newValue);
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.topContainer as any}>
            <View style={styles.destinationInputContainer as any} > 
                <TextInput style={styles.destinationInput} value={currentText} placeholderTextColor='#000' placeholder='Destinations' onChangeText={(currentInput) =>  updateValue(currentInput)} />
                <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={dragCallback} style={{flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", flex: 1}}>
                    <Text>Drag</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <ScrollView style={styles.searchResults as any} >
                <Text>Option1</Text>
                <Text>Option2</Text>
                <Text>Option3</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export class DestinationSearch extends React.Component {
    state: {currentDestinations: destinationInputProps[]}  // specify the type for the props
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderItem({ item, index, drag, isActive }: RenderItemParams<destinationInputProps>) {
        return <DestinationInput updateCallback={this.updateSingleValue} _currentTextValue={item._currentTextValue} id={item.id} dragCallback={drag} />
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView style={{maxHeight: 220}}>
                <DraggableFlatList 
                    data = { this.state.currentDestinations }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `draggable-item-${item.id}`}
                    renderItem = {this.renderItem}
                    onDragEnd={({ data }) => { console.log(this.state.currentDestinations); this.setCurrentDestinations(data)}}
                    extraData = { this.state.currentDestinations }
                />
            </ScrollView>
            <Button title={"Add"} disabled={this.state.currentDestinations.length >= 5} onPress={this.addDestination}></Button>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```